# Why does Mapbox only work sometimes on some browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mapbox

I am using mapbox on a website to geocode german addresses fetched from a MySQL database. The code works just fine so far, the issue i have though is that i am not able to predict when it is working on different devices.

For example: yesterday it worked on Chrome and Firefox on macOS but threw an error on Microsoft Edge on a Windows 10 PC. Today its working on Microsoft Edge on Windows 10, Chrome on a Windows 10 PC, but its not working on Safari on macOS or iOS where it used to work just fine yesterday.

my mapbox code looks like this:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = myAccessTokenInHere;
  var mapboxClient = mapboxSdk({ accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken });

  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';

  mapboxClient.geocoding.forwardGeocode({
    query: <?= $searchstring ?>,
    autocomplete: false,
    limit: 1
  })

  .send()
  .then(function(response) {
    if (
      response &&
      response.body &&
      response.body.features &&
      response.body.features.length
    ){
      var feature = response.body.features[0];
      var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/myCompaniesStyleInHere',
        center: feature.center,
        zoom: 16
      });

      new mapboxgl
      .Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(feature.center)
      .addTo(map);
    }
    
    // Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
  });
```

`$searchstring` is a .php variable that echoes the address in the following pattern: *'street houseNumber , Postal code/ZIP city'*.

The error in Safari is the following:
[image: error code]
In this case the specific streetname would be *Nürnberger Straße* - i'm guessing mapbox can't handle special characters?

Comment: "Not working" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "not working" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that is "not working", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? Please provide details of error messages, unexpected behaviour etc.

Comment: @ADyson i forgot, i'm sorry - i've edited my question.

Comment: 403 is generally a permissions issue. Seems you don't have permission on the server to access the URL you requested. I'm not sure the specific browsers are really the issue here. Are you supposed to log in to this API or anything?

Comment: Also...why have you tagged this with PHP? There appears to be no relationship to PHP.

Comment: I assume the missing `'` in `'myAccessTokenInHere;` is a typo here? And why replace your token in the code but leave it visible for others in your image?

Comment: because i am fetching the address from a mySQL database using PHP and then echo the address into js at "query: <?= $searchstring ?>," - but yeah, the error is not a php one obviously

Comment: Not sure if this makes any difference, but you could try to add single quotes `'` to your query: `query: '<?= $searchstring ?>',`